# Analog category_and (WP) in sql query

Tags: sql

There is a next parametr for the Loop in Wordpress - category_and, that allows to get all posts, **that have two categories at the same time**.

My loop was made using sql-query. What will be a conditional part that is an analog for "category_and" parametr?

At this moment I have the next conditional, for example:

```
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (1,3)
```

But it shows only posts that have the first category, and then the posts that have the second category.

Comment: An easy way to see this is to create a new `WP_Query` object and inspect `$your_query->request`

Comment: what is your sql?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Milo for the answer! This block of code selects posts that have two categories at the same time.

```
( ( SELECT COUNT(1) FROM wp_term_relationships 
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (35,33) AND object_id = wp_posts.ID ) = 2 )
```

Where 35,33 are categories IDs and 2 - number of categories.